# How can I query properties dynamically in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I am currently working on a project, that includes in an automatical flairing part.

### Basicly what this does:

- I have a table called **Fox**, with various columns. And some other tables refering to **Fox** (i.e. **CaughtChickens**).
- I want to have another table, that I can expand anytime, with 3 columns (other than ID ofc.) in my mind **FlairName**, **FlairColor**, and **FlairStoredProcedure**.
- I want to have a stored procedure that returns all **FlairName** where the **FlairStoredProcedure** returns 1, for a certain **FoxID**.

This way I can write a stored procedure that checks if a certain Fox caught a chicken and returns 1 if it did, and add a flair *Hunter* on the User UI.

### There are some cons with this:

- Every time I want a new flair I have to write a new stored procedure it (yeah I kinda can't short this one out).
- The stored procedures needs to have the same amount of in parameters (ie. **@FoxID**), and needs to return 1 or 0 (or select nothing when false, select the name if true (?))
- I need to use dynamicSQL in the stored procedure that collect these flairs, and I kinda don't want to use any dynamicSQL at all.

Isn't there a lot easier way to do this that I am missing?

> EDIT:

---

### Example:

I have a table **Fox**:

```
FoxID FoxName FoxColor FoxSize Valid
  1   Swiper    red      12      1
```

I would have a table **Flairs**

```
FlairID FlairName FlairStoredProcedure Valid
   1       Big       pFlairs_IsFoxBig    1
   2      Green    pFlairs_IsFoxGreen    1
```

I would have 3 stored procedures:

**pFox_Flairs**

```
@FoxID int
    DECLARE @CurrentFlairSP as varchar(100)
    DECLARE @CurrentIDIndex as varchar(100) = 1
    DECLARE @ResultFlairs as table(FlairName as varchar(50), FlairColor as integer)
WHILE @CurrentIDIndex <= (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM Flairs WHERE Valid <> 0)
BEGIN
 IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Flairs WHERE ID = @CurrentIDIndex AND VALID <> 0)
BEGIN
  SET @CurrentFlairSP = CONCAT((SELECT TOP 1 FlairStoredProcedure FROM Flairs WHERE ID = @CurrentIDIndex AND VALID <> 0), ' @FoxID=@FoxID')
  INSERT INTO @ResultFlairs
  EXEC (@CurrentFlairSP)
 END
 @CurrentIDIndex += 1
END
SELECT * FROM @ResultFlairs
```

**pFlairs_IsFoxBig**

```
@FoxID int
SELECT 'Big' WHERE EXISTS( SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Fox WHERE ID = @Fox AND FoxSize > 10)
```

**pFlairs_IsFoxGreen**

```
@FoxID int
SELECT 'Green' WHERE EXISTS( SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Fox WHERE ID = @Fox AND FoxColor = 'green')
```

Comment: I don't follow what you are asking here. What is your question? From the looks of description, you have a design flaw though; especially with a column named `FlairStoredProcedure` (which I assume contains the name of an object).

Comment: Yes that would be the name of the stored procedure I want to run dynamically, to check if a certain "property" is for true for the given "FoxID".

Comment: You haven't elaborated on what your question is though.

Comment: You're right to be suspicious of dynamic SQL, what's not clear is what you think going dynamic actually buys you here as opposed to having a better data model and/or more flexible client code that can handle it.

Comment: Edited my post with an example, I am sure there is an easier way to do this, than my code.

Comment: As you're going to have to create a new procedure with each flair (i.e. database release), I'd be inclined to remove the need for dynamic SQL by creating a function that `UNION`s all your checks together, rather than a new SP for each. [Something like this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=63b1fdf8e26fe4030a65bb2672f7ce57). It is possible to create rule builders so you can build all of your checks dynamically without schema changes, but this is significantly more complicated, and if you are only going to be adding/removing things sporadically it is probably not worth the effort

Comment: Generally when you uend up with this kind of design problem, you either transform the table into a long skinny table by unpivoting it, and create an EAV design (generally recommended against) or you change your procedure every time you get a new attribute (cumbersome to put in place, but works once you've done it)

Comment: This looks more like a job for sufficiently clever client code (Entity Framework if you're using .NET, for example) since presumably the criteria are open-ended and they don't need to be shared through the database as such (but could also use a library).

Comment: Side-note - `top 1` in an `exists` is redundant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a single table valued function that checks all the conditions:

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.GetFlairs ( @FoxID int )
RETURNS TABLE
AS RETURN

SELECT v.FlairName
FROM Fox f
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT 'Big'
    WHERE f.FoxSize > 10

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 'Green'
    WHERE f.FoxColor = 'green'
) v(FlairName)
WHERE f.FoxID = @FoxID;

go
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.GetFlairs(123);
```

If or when you add more attributes or conditions, simply add them into the function as another `UNION ALL`